# deploy with deployer fails

Tags: php, ssh, deployment

I'm having problem with deploying with the use of deployer, this is the first time i'm using any deployment tool. My teacher have made a guide for making it work but, I haven't been able to do a deploy.
So if anyone can tell me what i'm doing wrong please tell me.
here follows all the specs for my computer and my setup:

Computer:

> Operating system Windows 10 Home
>   Manufacturer ASUSTek Computer Inc. 
>   Model E403SA
>   Processor Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU N3700 @ 1.60GHz 1.60 GHz 
>   RAM 4.0 GB
>   64-bit operatingsystem, x64 based processor

.ssh/config file:

```
Host xxxxx
 ControlMaster no
 Hostname ssh.xxxxx.xx
 User xxxxxx_xxx
```

note that I added ControlMaster no becouse I read that the problem could be with ssh multiplexing but it but I got the same error with and without it...

deploy.php file ( in the root of the project):

```
<?php
namespace Deployer;

require 'recipe/common.php';

// Project name
set('application', 'blog');

// Project repository
set('repository', 'git@github.com:xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.git');

// [Optional] Allocate tty for git clone. Default value is false.
set('git_tty', true); 

// Shared files/dirs between deploys 
set('shared_files', ['config/dbinfo.json']);
set('shared_dirs', []);

// Writable dirs by web server 
set('writable_dirs', []);


// Hosts

host('ssh.xxxxxx.xx')
    ->set('deploy_path', '~/xxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxxxx')
    ->user('xxxxxx_xxx')
    ->port(22);    


// Tasks

desc('Deploy your project');
task('deploy:custom_webroot', function() {
    run("cd {{deploy_path}} && ln -sfn {{release_path}} public_html/xxxxxxxxxxxx");
});
task('deploy', [
    'deploy:info',
    'deploy:prepare',
    'deploy:lock',
    'deploy:release',
    'deploy:update_code',
    'deploy:shared',
    'deploy:writable',
    'deploy:clear_paths',
    'deploy:symlink',
    'deploy:unlock',
    'cleanup',
    'success'
]);

// [Optional] If deploy fails automatically unlock.
after('deploy:failed', 'deploy:unlock');
after('deploy', 'deploy:custom_webroot');
```

When i try to run dep deploy in the root of the project I get the flowing output:

```
$ dep deploy
✈︎ Deploying master on ssh.xxxxxx.xx
➤ Executing task deploy:prepare
✔ Executing task deploy:failed
➤ Executing task deploy:unlock


  [Deployer\Exception\RuntimeException]                                         
  The command "rm -f ~/blog.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxx/.dep/deploy.lock" failed.
  Exit Code: -1 (Unknown error)                                                 
  Host Name: ssh.xxxxx.xx                                                      
  ================                                                              
  mm_send_fd: sendmsg(2): Broken pipe                                           
  mux_client_request_session: send fds failed
```

any help would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: ok, yea perhaps I shulde try to deploy using some other tool, but still want to try and make this work.
Deployer is a Deployment tool for PHP https://deployer.org/

Answer (score 0):

Try using dep deploy:unlock and then use deploy normally.